# How to get structured JSON using KSQL?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, ksqldb

There are two tables in the `database`. For example: Layouts(Id, VenueId, Description) and Venues(Id, Adress, Phone). Layout table has reference key to Venues.
There are also two topics in Kafka accordingly tables. How can I send into my output topic `JSON` like this:

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Description": "LayoutDesc",
  "Venue": {
    "Id": 5,
    "Adress": "VenueAdress",
    "Description": "VenueDesc"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 5.1.1 you can't *construct* nested objects in KSQL (you can only read them). There is an open issue for this, please do upvote/comment on it: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2147